# Some gems work in development but don't get loaded in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Today I've had three issues with gems being loaded in the production environment. First one was HighVoltage, second with ActiveAdmin, and now with SASS (`uninitialized constant Sass::Rails::SassTemplate (NameError)`)

Everything seems to work on my development machine, but once I deploy the app to my nginx & unicorn server, it usually dies while `Refreshing Gem list`.

It seems to me, that the problem is in the order in which I specify gems in my Gemfile, but I can't figure out a correct way to add them.

I also don't understand, why is this happening only in production with Unicorn, and doesn't happen locally when using WEBrick.

Is there any rule for specifying order of gems in a Gemfile?

[Here's my Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/b1b0c6694d0f87d0b478)

Comment: I didn't know you could nest groups!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can specify gem order in a Gemfile -- Bundler goes through, analyzes dependencies, then installs in an order that works.

But why do you think the problem is one of gem order? That seems extremely unlikely. Let's see the error messages...

Comment: Error messages are always the same, uninitialized constant XYZ, usually I fix it by restarting unicorn multiple times and/or deleting Gemfile.lock & bundle again